# Delete entry from 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got 2 tables:
STUDENT (ID, name, surname, class)

SCORES (student_id, score_date (you can choose a date format), score , discipline)

I want to delete student Ionescu(and related entries from Score table)

I tried this

```
DELETE SCORE,STUDENT FROM STUDENT INNER JOIN SCORE 
WHERE Score.StudentID=Student.Id
AND Student.Name = 'Ionescu';
```

and it's not working. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the entries one by one, like this:

```
DELETE FROM SCORE WHERE score.StudentID in (select id from student where student.name = 'Ionescu');
```

This also makes the SQL-Query easier to read :-)

Ideally, you used the "ON DELETE CASCADE"-clause when creating the SCORE-Table - this would allow you to not worry about that SQL at all anymore, because the related entry will be deleted automatically as well. - Check this site for more Informations about Cascade: https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-use-the-postgresql-delete-cascade-1369

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a cascading delete constraint.  But in the meantime, you can do this in one statement using `returning`:

```
with d as (
      delete from student s
          where s.name = 'Ionescu'
          returning *
     )
delete from score sc
    where sc.studentid in (select d.id from d);
```